# Nodejs Express: Getting different output in console.log and callback

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum, call, web3js

I have a smart contract deployed on Kovan, which contains a getter function:

```
function getOrderStatus(uint _orderId) public view returns(bool shipped, bool arrived, bool payed) {
    return (orders[_orderId].shipped, orders[_orderId].arrived, orders[_orderId].payed); 
}
```

If I call the function via web3 I get the following output on the console, which is fine!:

```
Result {
  '0': false,
  '1': false,
  '2': false,
  shipped: false,
  arrived: false,
  payed: false }
```

But if I try to forward the returned object via a `callback function` to provide it e.g. via an API, I get the following output on my Browser:

```
[object Object]
```

The only difference is instead of `console.log(returnValue)` --> `callback(returnValue)` at the end of the following code:

```
function getOrderStatus(_orderId, callback) {
    contractABI.methods.getOrderStatus(_orderId).call()
        .then(returnValue => callback(returnValue));
}
```

The function is then being called via `Express`

```
app.get('/api/getOrderStatus', function(req, res) {    
    orderId = req.query.orderId;        
    getOrderStatus(orderId, function(error, data) {
        if (!error) {
            res.send(data);
        }
        else 
        {
            res.send(error);    
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: try using res.json(data) insted of res.send(data)

Comment: Thanky you for the feedback, then I get `"[object Object]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `getOrderStatus()` function is like this:

```
function getOrderStatus(_orderId, callback) {
    contractABI.methods.getOrderStatus(_orderId).call()
        .then(returnValue => callback(returnValue));
}
```

... then your result is in `returnValue`, right? If you then call your `callback` function like described above, then the first parameter is your data.

In your route, you are calling the callback with the `error` parameter at first parameter, so I guess it should be this way:

```
app.get('/api/getOrderStatus', function(req, res) {    
    orderId = req.query.orderId;        
    getOrderStatus(orderId, function(data, error) {  // <--- changed order of parameters
        if (!error) {
            res.json(data);
        } else {
            res.send(error);    
        }
    });    
});
```

Hope that helps ...